# Creating seperate sheets based on row count

Tags: excel, vba

I know this has been discussed and I have gotten the below code from several different post on Stackoverflow. My problem is, if column "A" has rows not equal to the hard coded number (rowsPerSheet = 10), it will add the extra rows back to the original page. If I have 35 rows, I will get 3 worksheets with worksheets 2 & 3 being correct, but worksheet 1 will have rows 1-10 + rows 31-35). What should I be changing? Please excuse excess code, I just want to make sure I place answer in correct place in the process.

```
Sub SaveSheets()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim nUserInput As String
Dim wsMasterSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim rowsPerSheet As Integer
nUserInput = InputBox("Enter Job Number:", "Collect User Input")
Set wsMasterSheet = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

rowsPerSheet = 10
rowCount = Application.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A:A"))
sheetCount = Round(rowCount / rowsPerSheet, 0)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To sheetCount - 1 Step 1
With wb
'Add new sheet
.Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

wsMasterSheet.Range("A1:M1").EntireRow.Copy     Destination:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1").End(xlUp)

wsMasterSheet.Range("A2" & ":M" & (rowsPerSheet + 1)).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
wsMasterSheet.Range("A2" & ":M" & (rowsPerSheet + 1)).EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.Name = "Valves " + CStr(((.Sheets.Count - 1) * rowsPerSheet + 1))
End With


Next

wsMasterSheet.Name = "Valves End"

Application.EnableEvents = True


Dim strPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strPath = "\\Server Name\Engineering\iPortal Valves\"
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Copy
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Close True, strPath & nUserInput & "_" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
Next

Application.Quit
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Trying to think through this, I am wondering if something could be added using

```
lastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Row + Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
```

In non-coding terminology:

If the lastRow is greater than RowsPerSheet and less than (2*RowsPerSheet - 1)
Then RowsPerSheet = (lastRow - RowsPerSheet).

Would RowsPerSheet need to be "Dim" to allow the code to overwrite hard value? If I understand the code process correctly, if the coding to reset the RowsPerSheet falls with the "For/Next" the Hard coded number will remain when macro is run again.

The additional questions here are 1) How could the code be written, 2) Where should the code reside?

*I have modified the above code to what I have been able to make work. The original sheet is split into separate sheets based on rowPerSheet and than individual files are created and saved to specified location.*

*Thanks to all the people who have made posts on Stackoverflow, all coding has been pulled from various posts.*